# How to set up sub-categories for author pages?

Tags: categories, customization, author

I am setting up Wordpress for a school. They want to enable teachers to have their own section of the site where they can create posts in different categories (assignments, events, etc).

I know that Wordpress supports multiple authors and that I can show posts by those authors out of the box by going to `http://domain.com/authors/{username}`.

However, instead of just showing all of the posts from different categories in one loop, I would like to allow the user to view posts by category and they can choose from a link menu.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?  Is there a way to create a url that would filter posts by author AND category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to make use of an [author template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates). It will allow you to control how the author page is displayed, so you can add what you pictured into there.

You can then register a [rewrite endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API#add_rewrite_endpoint.28.29) to create the multiple areas of the author page. In the template just check on which "subpage" you are and display the tabs and listing accordingly.

That's basically doing [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) then which is pretty well documented, so should be an easy start.

Comment: Have you seen any tutorials on how to properly add an endpoint like you're suggesting? I'm having a hard time grasping exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: adding and reading an endpoint: https://gist.github.com/705545