# Custom post types, taxonomies, and permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

This is driving me nuts and I'm sure it's simple but nothing I search for comes up with a simple structure (everything is very complex).

I have a custom post type `product_listing` and a custom taxonomy of `product_cat` (which is hierarchical and should be have like categories).

I simply want my URLs to look like this:

```
mysite.com/products/category1/product-name1 
mysite.com/products/category2/product-name2
```

But for the life of me, no matter what I do, I'm getting the dreaded 404 issue. Pages work okay and Posts work okay but my custom posts don't work correctly.  They're showing up as:

```
mysite.com/products/product-name1
mysite.com/products/product-name2
```

Which actually *works*!  It's just that I want to see my custom taxonomy in there plus I want to be able to access the `taxonomy.php` template I have setup by going to:

```
mysite.com/products/category1/
mysite.com/products/category2/
```

None of my slugs are the same, nor do I want them to be.  Here is the post type and taxonomy part of my `functions.php` file:

```
///// CUSTOM POST TYPES /////

// register the new post type
register_post_type( 'product_listing', array( 
    'labels'                 => array(
        'name'               => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name'      => __( 'Product' ),
        'add_new'            => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Create New Product' ),
        'edit'               => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
        'view'               => __( 'View Products' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No products found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in trash' ),
        'parent'             => __( 'Parent Product' ),
    ),
    'description'           => __( 'This is where you can create new products on your site.' ),
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'menu_position'         => 2,
    'menu_icon'             => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/tag_orange.png',
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    '_builtin'              => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => true ),
    'query_var'             => true,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions' ),
) );


//hook into the init action and call create_book_taxonomies when it fires
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_taxonomies', 0 );
//add_action('admin_init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');

//create two taxonomies, genres and writers for the post type "book"
function create_product_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Categories' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Categories:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Category' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy( 'product_cat', array( 'product_listing' ), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        //'rewrite'     => true,
        'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => '%category%', 'with_front' => true ),
    ) );

    // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Scents', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Scent', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'               =>  __( 'Search Scents' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Scents' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Scents' ),
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Scent' ), 
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Scent' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Scent' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Scent Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate scents with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove scents' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used scents' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Scents' ),
    ); 

    register_taxonomy( 'scent', 'product_listing', array(
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        //'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'scents' ),
    ) );
}
```

I also have another custom taxonomy of `scents` that I'd ideally like to have some kind of friendly url but I'm more open on this.  I'd like to maybe access a list of all scents by going to `mysite.com/products/scents` but they don't have to be category specific.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Change `slug` in your post type arguments to `products/%product_cat%`, and `slug` in your taxonomy arguments to just `products`, then flush your rewrite rules. WordPress should now handle `/products/my-product-cat/post-name/`!

Now finally, we need to help WordPress a little with generating permalinks (out of the box, it won't recognise the permastruct tag `%product_cat%`):

```
/**
 * Inject term slug into custom post type permastruct.
 * 
 * @link   http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/1685
 * 
 * @param  string  $link
 * @param  WP_Post $post 
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_5308_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'product_listing' ) {
        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) )
            $link = str_replace( '%product_cat%', current( $terms )->slug, $link );
    }

    return $link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_5308_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

One thing to note, this will just grab the first product category for the post *ordered by name*. If you're assigning multiple categories to a single product, I can easily change how it determines which one to use in the permalink.

Lemme know how you get on with this, and we can tackle the other issues!

Comment: Oh WOW I'm in awe!  This WORKED!  Finally!  I didn't ever think anything would!!!  thank you SOOOOOO much!!! ............ Now, how would I generate a link (something like the_permalink) to grab the taxonomy url on its own? */products/my-product-cat/*

Comment: I think I got that worked out^^^ ............ but now I'm stuck on Pagination.  Seems to break when using any pagination (custom function or builtin) as /products/my-product-cat/ looks okay but /products/my-product-cat/page/2/ returns a 404 and drops the taxonomy.php file in favor of the index.php file.  I've tried everything I could find and still nothing.

Comment: Would you consider changing the single product rewrites to `product/cat-name/product-name`? (note the singularity) The trouble is the rewrite rule for the taxonomy pagination isn't triggered, because it's getting caught by an earlier rule for single products!

Comment: I'm open to it. But to wrap my head around it, would that mean products would have a different URL path if you're viewing a single product page vs. a 'category' page? So single would be *product/cat-name/prod-name* but cats would be *products/cat-name/* ?  Wouldn't that sort of defeat the purpose of "human friendly" urls? I have a hard time helping my clients learn the wp dashboard let alone that difference... If I'm misunderstanding pls let me know! I might also be happy with NO front directory, such as *product-cat/product-nam* and just *product-cat/*. Could that work?

Comment: You got it - though I'd say it *is* "human friendly", as there is a clear distinction between archives (`products/`) and singular items (`product/`). And no, I'd keep the 'front directory' - it helps keep a clear distinction from posts and pages, plus otherwise you might end up with performance issues (i.e. verbose rewrite rules).

Comment: Ok, how about keeping your suggestion above but using terms less closely related?  Say... **product/cat-name/product-name/** for single product pages... and something **categories/cat-name/** for the cat archive pages?  What would I need to modify in the above code to get that to work?

Comment: I tested that plugin that the other answer suggested and it seems to be working fine for **/products/cat-name/prod-name/** AND **/products/cat-name/** ... is that a viable option?

Comment: It might be that the plugin generates the rewrite rules manually in an order that works - the only thing I'd do is keep an eye on the performance - use `<?php timer_stop(true); ?>` and `<?php echo get_num_queries(); ?>` somewhere in your `footer.php`, and see what sort of averages you get when requesting taxonomy archives and single products.

Comment: Did you guys find a way to fix this? I've tried the code @TheDeadMedic suggested and the plugin but neither work successfully. If so, please take a look at my question. Thanks you! - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40587/shouldnt-this-be-easy-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-permalink

Answer (score 7):

Thanks @TheDeadMechanic, your answer helped me out, but only partially.  I wanted to do the same thing @RodeoRamsey asked for, but with nested categories (ie: `mysite.com/products/category1/child-category-1/grandchild-category-1/product-name`) and your solution didn't work for that.

I finally came up with an extended solution to my question that works, so if anyone else  needs nested categories/subcategories you can see a [detailed solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) on my own question.  Hope it helps others, and thanks for the initial steps.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure wp supports that structure out of the box - but you can very easily create your own rewrite rules to do so.

Check out a previous answer here [Author url rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5275/author-url-rewrite).

You can change the line

```
$newrules['author/([^/]+)/songs/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=songs&author=$matches[1]';
```

to something like

```
$newrules['products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=product_listing&product_cat=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]';
```

the product_cat part here may be superfluous - I am not sure if it is needed.

You can add any rules you like and they will have priority over the inbuilt ones.

Comment: Well isn't that interesting.  Oh boy, I think custom rewrite rules are beyond me.  I tried the above code (and the rest of it from the other post) and nothing changed.  I flushed everything and then tried again and still no change, so I commented out all the rewrite rules set in the custom post types and taxonomies and flushed and STILL nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it was driving me crazy before setting the permalink for custom post type. I found a plugin to handle the custom post type. It's very easy to use.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-permalinks/
WP should add this as a core feature!
Leo

Comment: I had seen this one before and refrained from using it because it said "for non-hierarchical" taxonomies.  I had one that was set to hierarchical so I didn't think it would work, but so far, it seems to have done the trick!  Plus, it seems to be working to accomplish the **/products/cat-name/prod-name/** structure I was trying to achieve (see comment to other answer).  @TheDeadMedic, is this a viable option? Or should I stick with the rewrites in the functions.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's pretty easy. You just need one line. Here's my code

```
function create_product_taxonomies()
{
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Category', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Categories'),
        'all_items' => __('All Categories'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Categories'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Categories:'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Category'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Category'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Category'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Category Name'),
        'menu_name' => __('Category'),
    );

    register_taxonomy('product_cat', array('product_listing'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('hierarchical' => true),
    ));
```

And applied to the generated taxonomy for my Reviews CPT from GenerateWP.com. I'm using this on my own WordPress site, https://www.wpstarters.com

```
function reviews_category_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Reviews Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'reviews_category' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Reviews Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'reviews_category' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Reviews Category', 'reviews_category' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Review Categories', 'reviews_category' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Review Category', 'reviews_category' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Review Category:', 'reviews_category' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Review Category Name', 'reviews_category' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Review Category', 'reviews_category' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Review Category', 'reviews_category' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Review Category', 'reviews_category' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Review Category', 'reviews_category' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'reviews_category' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'reviews_category' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'reviews_category' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Review Categories', 'reviews_category' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'reviews_category' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'reviews_category' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No Review Categories', 'reviews_category' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Review Categories list', 'reviews_category' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Review Categories list navigation', 'reviews_category' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true ),
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'reviews_category', array( 'wps_reviews' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'reviews_category_taxonomy', 0 );
```

All you need it so put the 'rewrite' => array('hierarchical' => true),