# Custom post type taxonomies URL rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

What I want to achieve is an online listing catalog with a URL like this:

```
www.example.com/drawing-tools/brand/type/material/color/
```

In this example, I have a custom post type named "drawing-tools" with 4 custom taxonomies for it: "brand", "type", "material", "color"

When a user access a URL like:

```
www.example.com/drawing-tools/rotring/mechanical-pencil/plastic/black/
```

it gets all the items that match those criteria.

The tricky part is that all of the taxonomies are required to be in a URL. So something like this:

```
www.example.com/drawing-tools/plastic/black/
```

would simply return an 404 error page.

So my main question is:

How exactly can I have all of the taxonomies in the URL in that form and return an 404 error page if one taxonomy is missing?

I was thinking to write a rewrite rule that would take those uri segments and pass them as arguments to a query based on the ['Query Multiple Taxonomies'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin and return that 404 error if one segment is missing. But I don't know how to accomplish this. Is there any solutions that you can give me?

**[Update 1]**

The rewrite rule would basically take this URL:

```
www.example.com/drawing-tools/rotring/mechanical-pencil/plastic/black/
```

and make it into:

```
www.example.com/?drawing-tools_name=rotring+mechanical-pencil+plastic+black
```

The above structure is required by the ['Query Multiple Taxonomies'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/) plugin.

**[Update 2]**

I've given up to the Query Multiple Taxonomies plugin and instead I've switched to WP 3.1. Now, with the help from this [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks) I've managed to get to work those taxonomies like I wanted.

Here is the full code:

```
register_post_type('drawing-tools', array(
    'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Drawing Tools' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Drawing Tool' ),
            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Drawing Tool' ),
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Drawing Tool' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Drawing Tool' ),
            'view' => __( 'View Drawing Tools' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Drawing Tool' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Drawing Tools' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No items found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in trash' ),
            'parent' => __( 'Parent Drawing Tool' ),
            ),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
    '_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "drawing-tools/%brand%/%type%/%material%/%color%"), // Permalinks format
    'has_archive' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports' => array('author')
));

  register_taxonomy('brand',array('drawing-tools'), array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Brands', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Brand', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Brands' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Brands' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Brand' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Brand:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Brands' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Brand' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Brand' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Unit Brand' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Brands' ),
                ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'drawing-tools' ),
  ));

  register_taxonomy('type',array('drawing-tools'), array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Types' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Types' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Type:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Types' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Type' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Type' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Type' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Types' ),
                ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'drawing-tools/%brand%' ),
  ));

 register_taxonomy('material',array('drawing-tools'), array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Materials', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Material', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Materials' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Materials' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Material' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Material:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Material' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Material' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Material' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Material Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Materials' ),
                ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'drawing-tools/%brand%/%type%' ),
  ));

 register_taxonomy('color',array('drawing-tools'), array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Colors', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Color', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Colors' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Colors' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Color' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Color:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Color' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Color' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Color' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Color Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Colors' ),
                ),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'drawing-tools/%brand%/%type%/%material%' ),
  ));  


function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'drawing-tools')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'brand'))
        $link = str_replace('%brand%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type'))
        $link = str_replace('%type%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'material'))
        $link = str_replace('%material%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'color'))
        $link = str_replace('%color%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);      
    return $link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

Now, when a user access the link:

```
www.example.com/drawing-tools/rotring/mechanical-pencil/plastic/black/
```

everything works as expected. The problem is that the user can also access a partial structure like this

```
www.example.com/drawing-tools/rotring/
```

and still get results according to those taxonomies.

How can I restrict a user from accessing such a URL and instead returning a 404 error message?

Comment: can you have taxonmy term page using drawing-tools/%brand%/%type% as slug for example? it's not working for me... i get drawing-tools/%brand%/%type%/my-term-name and it gives a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple and I don't know why it took me so long to find it on the Codex. You must make use of the `$wp_query` class.

So, in the template, before calling the loop, set a variable to hold the returned data:

```
$vars = $wp_query->query_vars;
```

And then, check if the required taxonomies are set:

```
if ( isset( $vars['brand']) && isset( $vars['type'] ) && isset( $vars['material'] ) && isset( $vars['size'] ) )
```

If they are continue with the loop. If not:

```
global $wp_query; 
status_header('404');
$wp_query->set_404();
```

I wonder, though, if this is the most optimum solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe WP 3.1 introduced a fix for what you're describing... from the codex:

- Custom Content Type Improvements - allows developers to generate archive pages, and have better menu and capability controls. Read more in the article Post Types.
- Advanced Queries - allows developers to query multiple taxonomies and custom fields

I haven't used either of these improvements yet so I can't comment specifically, but it seems like that's what you're looking for. Good luck!

Comment: I've moved to version 3.1 and indeed it works but it doesn't fit the 404 criteria, specifically that I want users to be able to use all of the taxonomies at once and not separated. Right now a user can access `www.example.com/drawing-tools/rotring/` and have a list of all items that match that taxonomy but I want him to only be able to access the structure with all of the taxonomies: `www.example.com/drawing-tools/rotring/mechanical-pencil/plastic/black/`. How can I return a 404 when he wants to access a partial taxonomy structure?