# Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?

Tags: multi-taxonomy-query

I have the following setup:

**post types**
fashion

**Global Taxonomies (linked to all post types)**
issue_name

**Singular Taxonomies (just linked to fashion post type)**
men
women

I want my permalink structure to be:
/%issue_name%/%posttype%/%postname%
which would output:
myissue/fashion/men/mypostname

I've tried Taxonomic SEO Permalink plugin which works well for Taxonomy based permalinks, but my permalink has taxonomy AND posttype & postname..

Thankyou for helping!!

Comment: The only solution i've found is from this post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11582/custom-post-type-taxonomies-url-rewrite

Comment: But that only deals with taxonomy based permalinks, I require taxonomy & post type mixed

Comment: You would need to have a constant that starts the permalink:  /issue/%issue_name%/%posttype%/%postname%

Answer (score 1):

I could’t make it to work. May be it is not possible. I tried a plugin to set it and I was able to achieve /%issue_name%/%post_type%/%post_id%/ but not /%issue_name%/%post_type%/%post_name%/

The plugin removes that latter one by itself. Moreover I would strongly advise against such a permalink structure as it gets very taxing on WordPress performance with growing number of posts.