# Permalink URL connection between two custom types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

We use latest WP 5.2, and the super plugins Advanced Custom Fields Pro (ACF Pro) and CPT UI. In our website taxonomy, we need to have events, within which we have talks and workshops.

Example structure:

```
Event 1
  |__ Workshop A 
  |__ Workshop B 

Event 2
  |__ Workshop C
  |__ Workshop D
```

We have therefore setup two custom post types: Events, and Workshops. We first create events. Then, when creating each workshop, we have a custom-field association with a related field and can thus create workshops *within* each event. In other words, each workshop is associated with a pre-created event. This works beautifully and ACF Pro is a stellar help.

However, the URLs created by Wordpress follow the custom posts as if they're unrelated:

```
/events/event-1 
/events/event-2 
/workshops/workshop-a
/workshops/workshop-b
```

What we'd like is to manifest the association in actual permalink URLs:

```
/event-1/workshop-a
/event-1/workshop-b
/event-2/workshop-c
/event-2/workshop-d
```

I found some questions on the site related to this, but they're either too localized, or [deal with the wp_query](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11582/custom-post-type-taxonomies-url-rewrite) inside already working permalinks, or have 0 answers. Any ideas how to set this up in Wordpress? Many thanks.

Comment: You could make the event CPT hierarchical and then make events the parent and workshops the children.  This would set the slugs exactly how you want.

Comment: Thanks @rudtek. That sounds promising. For both *Events* (slug: `events`) and *Workshops* (slug: `workshops`) -- I have the 'Hierarchical' menu set to `TRUE`. In Workshops setting I write inside the `Parent` textbox: `events`. But this doesn't work. What should I do differently?

Comment: Just to add, I'm speaking of the *CPT UI* plugin, not hardcoding all this custom post type and fields functionality into my singular theme.

Comment: My suggestion was to get rid of the workshop CPT altogether.  Create an event "event 1"  save.  Choose add new event, name it"workshop 1" then set it's parent to event 1.

Comment: Thank you Rudtek, but that is confusing to simple business users who will use the CMS. It's not a bad idea at all, just not very conceptually meaningful to enter workshops inside a parent Event. Will think about this.