# custom post type and custom taxonomy url conflict

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error

I have custom post type called `paintings` and it has a custom taxonomy called `paintings_category`.

Currently I have this situation:

- `example.com/paintings/`

  > A page using `page-paintings.php`
- `example.com/paintings_category/landscape/`

  > Lists all `landscape` items in `taxonomy.php`
- `example.com/paintings/landscape/painting-title/`

  > Displays single painting post types, eg. `single-paintings.php`

If I try changing the slug as below, I get a 404 error on:

`example.com/paintings/landscape/painting-title/`

```
register_taxonomy( 
    'paintings_category', array('paintings'), 
    array( 
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => 'Categories', 
        'singular_label' => 'Category', 
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'paintings' )
    )
);
```

I'd like behaviour to be:

- `example.com/paintings/`

  > ideally list `paintings_category` as links
- `example.com/paintings/landscape/`

  > lists all items of `landscape` taxonomy
- `example.com/paintings/landscape/painting-title/`

  > displays single item

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

I tried adding `paintings` as a parent of `landscape` category in `paintings_category` but this still leaves me with a 404 on the single.

Comment: Simply put, you can't have pages, a custom post type and a taxonomy all share a common URL, that's simply beyond what the rewrite rules are capable of handling. Put it this way, if i request `example.com/paintings/something`, how could WordPress know if i'm referring to a page, a post type or a taxonomy? (it can't).

Comment: I realised there are conflicts in trying to get that structure the way I have it currently, but I was hoping to do it another way. Can I have a taxonomy hierarchy thus: /paintings/landscape/painting-title/ and not have a page called 'paintings' is that possible? if so how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out it is indeed possible : )

I eventually found most of the answer in this post: [Custom post types, taxonomies, and permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks)

Then I got `single-paintings.php` to paginate within selected taxonomy with this plugin: **Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus** (which looks like it could be dropped into `functions.php` if you wanted to do it without plugins).

Hope this helps someone!