# Taxonomy, Terms, and Template Files

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, templates

I have post type 'product' and hierarchical taxonomy 'types' attached to it. In this taxonomy, I have terms: 'dry-clean', 'washer', etc. With several sub terms on each terms.

In my situation, I need to display, eg:

1. http://example.com/types/washer -> display all sub terms on it
2. http://example.com/types/washer/{subterm} -> display all posts on it

**My questions is:**

1. How do I get permalink URL for parent terms? I try URL above, but it result in 404.
2. How the template files work for that kind of problem?

   1. is `taxonomy-types-washer.php` enough for case #1? or should I create `taxonomy-types.php` and create the logic there?
   2. in my mind, after scanning [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png), I might need `taxonomy-types-{term_parent}.php` to list all sub terms and `taxonomy-types.php` to list all product in sub terms.
   3. ultimately, to display each product, I will have to create `single-product.php`
3. On a slightly unrelated problem. I find that `archive-{posttype}.php` doesn't work when I don't have any post on it. Is there any solution for this? (*should I create different question, or stick with this one*)?

**UPDATE**

I checked my `rewrite_rules` options and it doesn't list [types] at all. I don't know why. To test it, I change my slug into `product-types`, flush permalink and it list this:

```
[product-types/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[product-types/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[product-types/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[product-types/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]
```

So I guess it's registered now. I try to load URL `product-types/washer` it goes to 404. I try to load URL `index.php?types=washer`. It too, goes 404. Right now, I have this files:

- taxonomy-types-washer.php
- taxonomy-types.php

So, I don't know what's wrong with this one :(.

**UPDATE #2**

I find the problem. It's because I missed `'rewrite'=>array('hierarchical'=>true)`

Here's the new `rewrite_rules`:

```
[product-types/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[product-types/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
[product-types/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
[product-types/(.+?)/?$] => index.php?types=$matches[1]
```

Comment: I know this can be done http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks/5313#5313 but for "non-hierarchical" taxonomies.

Comment: You should create a new question for point 3.

Comment: @scribu, I'll create that question tonight, when I'm back home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These types of URLs are supported since WP 3.1:

```
register_taxonomy( 'types', 'post', array(
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true ),
  ...
);
```

Remember to flush the rewrite rules after making the change.

The template you would use for both parent and child terms is taxonomy-types.php:

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();

if ( 0 == $current_term->parent ) {
  // it's a parent term; display it's child terms using wp_list_categories() etc.
} else {
  // it's a child term; display the posts using The Loop etc.
}
```