# Custom post type Permalinks with hierarchical Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, hierarchical

I Would use Custom Post Type and hierarchical Taxonomies with same Slug. Fortunately I found a good solution based on post_type_link filter [here from TheDeadMedic.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
mysite.com/products/category1/product-name1 
mysite.com/products/category2/product-name2
mysite.com/products/category1/subcategory1/product-name1
mysite.com/products/category2/subcategory2/product-name2
...
```

The only problem is subcategory pages get 404.

So these URLs work:

```
mysite.com/products/category1/product-name1
mysite.com/products/category1/subcategory1/product-name1
```

But subcategory pages don't work in hierarchical structure:

```
mysite.com/products/category1/subcategory1
mysite.com/products/category2/subcategory2
```

I can only access these subcategories without hierarchical structure. So these URLs work:

```
mysite.com/products/subcategory1
mysite.com/products/subcategory2
```

Have you got any idea how I could extend [TheDeadMedic's solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks?answertab=active#tab-top) to hierarchical taxonomies too.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the taxonomy registration:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'hierarchical' => true )
```

Comment: This doesn't fix this problem.