# Shouldn't this be easy?! Custom post type/custom taxonomy permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

So this is driving me absolutely insane.  I've spend days trying to fix this and I can't work out why this is so difficult as surely this is a very common permalink structure!

I looked through hundreds of answers and posts and none of them seem to solve the problem.

I simply want this structure:

```
mysite.com/custom-post-type/custom-taxonomy-term/post-name
```

So I achieve the following:

```
mysite.com/literature - all literature posts
mysite.com/literature/fiction - all literature posts with 'fiction' term
mysite.com/literature/fiction/mybook - the post
```

Every time I try something I get 404 errors or the pagnination doesn't work.

I don't understand why this is so hard!

Any help really appreciated!

Thank you

======================================================
==================**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**==================

Currently I'm registering the post type and taxonomy as follows:

```
register_post_type('literature',$args);
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'literature/books','with_front' => false),

register_taxonomy('literature_category',array('literature'), array(
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'literature','with_front' => false ),
```

If I register both as 'literature' I get a 404 on the mysite.com/literature page but this displays my permalink as: `mysite.com/literature/books/mybook`

After following the advice on this question - [Custom post types, taxonomies, and permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks)

I've added this to my functions:

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'literature')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'literature_category'))
        $link = str_replace('%literature_category%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

And changed my post type to `'slug' => 'literature/%literature_category%'`
And changed my taxonomy to `'slug' => 'literature'`

This works great except that on `mysite.com/literature` pagination doesn't work so I get a 404 error on the following url:

`mysite.com/literature/page/2/`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This answer got me the closest - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks - but then it didn't work with pagination and the suggested plugin didn't work either

Comment: Cool, glad I asked, that saved me some time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the advice on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks) as you did already, but add this to your code:

```
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'fix_literature_category_pagination' );
function fix_literature_category_pagination( $wp_rewrite ) {
    unset($wp_rewrite->rules['literature/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']);
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'literature/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=literature',
        'literature/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=literature&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        'literature/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?literature_category=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Lastly, go to Settings > Permalinks and hit save. If it still doesn't work, save your permalinks again. Sometimes I feel like you have to save 'em twice, but who knows. Anyway, Let me know how you make out. Note that Computer Science Standard Answer #1 applies: **It Works For Me**... ;-)

### From the land of TMI...

For reference, the reason *why* the pages don't work by default is that WordPress puts in a rewrite rule for literature/%literature_category%/%book%/%page%, which makes total sense if you think about it. So your default permalinks have these competing rules in this order:

```
[literature/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?literature_category=$matches[1]&book=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]
[literature/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?literature_category=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
```

All we're really doing here is changing the order of these by unsetting the latter (we can keep it in, but then every rewrite thereafter has one more regex to run on page load) and adding it to the beginning of the array.

*Fun fact:* If you ever have a "book" entitled "page" and it has multiple pages, this order will conflict and its subsequent pages won't work!

Comment: Gosh, it just occurred to me that my syntax was wrong here. Funny enough, it works for me and when I fix it, it doesn't work. I'll keep at it and update my answer when I figure it out...

Comment: Thanks for your help Matthew. I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work. I've added more information to my question which hopefully explains it better!

Comment: And if it also helps, here's a link to the site - http://bit.ly/xvclET

Comment: Ok, my apologies for the confusion. Had a little brain gas there (must have had some brain beans recently). My answer has been updated, and again it works for me. Remember to save over your permalinks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any different to the permalink structure :(

Comment: Oh ok, I saw your updated question. So it's not that /literature/fiction/page/2 doesn't work, it's that /literature/page/2 doesn't work, is that right? If so, that's an easy fix, we'll do the same thing up a level

Comment: Thanks again Matthew. Yes, literature/page/2 doesn't work. However, your updated answer isn't working either and my brain is getting even more fried! My literature taxonomy is called 'literature_category' but the rewrite is 'literature' as per that answer I was working from. Also to note mysite.com/literature is a page called literature.php where it queries the post type 'literature'. Hmmm I'm feeling really lost!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2336/discussion-between-matthew-boynes-and-fxfuture)

Comment: Working perfectly on the site, except for one minor issue... I'm using Breadcrumb Nav XT, and now 'Literature' in the breadcrumb trail links to mysite.com/literature/%literature_category%/ generating a bad request error

Comment: Fixed by changing the linked breadcrumb template to <a title="Go to Literature." href="/literature">Literature</a> :)

Comment: I don't think you need to click the Save button on the Permalink Settings page. Just visiting the page will flush the rewrite rules.