# Custom Permalinks for Custom Taxonomies/Post Types -> Top Level Pages not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have created a custom post type called "artists".
These are categorized by the custom taxonomy "style".

I do have this:

> ./photography/edward-example (single page with details)
>
> ./photography/ (archive page which lists all artists in "category"/custom taxonomy "style" "photography")

(for example: photography as style, Edward Example as artist)

I achieved this because I used the technique described in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/34790) for the custom taxonomy.

The problem is, now my other pages (e.g. "./about") will not work. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Can you post your taxonomy and custom post type code please?

Comment: This has been covered quite extensively on WPSE. In fact, if you go to the [permalinks tag](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalinks), which you added to your question, several of the questions on the first page are devoted to this very topic.

Comment: I updated my question. My permalinks are now okay, but my other links are not working.
I followed these [instructions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/34790)