# How to change custom post type pemalink Hierarcy

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permalinks

When we set permalink as `Post name` and go to wordpress any default post Like "Testing 123" single page its link looks like this

```
localhost/foo_articles/testing-123
```

Now i when we change our permalink to `Custom Structure` and set value like `%category%/%postname%`, the link looks like this

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/testing/testing-123/
```

testing is my category slug

**Now the main part of my question is**

I make a plugin where i create a post type `foo_articles` and custom taxonomy `foo_categories`

Its work perfectly. When i click on a category its link looks like this

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/foo_category/junk-food/
```

and when i click on an article for a single page, its link looks like this

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/foo_articles/how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children/
```

foo_articles is my post type and its a change able

Now my question is how can i set links that when a user set permalinks `Custom Structure` and set value like `%category%/%postname%` my link also change like above default post single page.

```
http://localhost/foo_articles/article cat slug/how-to-reduce-the-intake-of-junk-food-in-children/
```

Here is custom post type code:

```
add_action('init', 'foo_articles');
function foo_articles() {

    $foo_slug = 'foo_articles';
    $foo_slug = get_option('foo_plugin_slug');

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  =>  __('Foo', 'fff'),
        'singular_name'         =>  __('Foo', 'fff'),
        'all_items'             =>  __('Articles', 'fff'),
        'add_new'               =>  __('New Article', 'fff'),
        'add_new_item'          =>  __('Add New Article', 'fff'),
        'edit_item'             =>  __('Edit Article', 'fff'),
        'new_item'              =>  __('New Article', 'fff'),
        'view_item'             =>  __('View Articles', 'fff'),
        'search_items'          =>  __('Search Articles', 'fff'),
        'not_found'             =>  __('Nothing found', 'fff'),
        'not_found_in_trash'    =>  __('Nothing found in Trash', 'fff'),
        'parent_item_colon'     =>  ''
    );

    $foo_rewrite = array(
        'slug'          =>  FOO_PLUGIN_SLUG, // i define this in plugin index file
        'with_front'    =>  true,
        'pages'         =>  false,
        'feeds'         =>  true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                =>  $labels,
        'public'                =>  true,
        'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
        'show_ui'               =>  true,
        'query_var'             =>  true,
        'menu_icon'             =>  plugin directory.'images/icon-foo.png',
        'capability_type'       =>  'post',
        'hierarchical'          =>  false,
        'menu_position'         =>  3,
        'supports'              =>  array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments','tags'),
        'rewrite'               =>  $foo_rewrite,
        'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     =>  true,
        'can_export'            =>  true,
        'has_archive'           =>  true,
        'exclude_from_search'   =>  true
    );

    register_post_type( 'foo_articles' , $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'foo_taxonomies', 0 );

// Article taxonamy
function foo_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              =>  __( 'Article Category', 'fff'),
        'singular_name'     =>  __( 'Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'all_items'         =>  __( 'All Article Categories', 'fff' ),
        'parent_item'       =>  __( 'Parent Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'parent_item_colon' =>  __( 'Parent Article Category:', 'fff' ),
        'edit_item'         =>  __( 'Edit Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'update_item'       =>  __( 'Update Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'add_new_item'      =>  __( 'Add New Article Category', 'fff' ),
        'new_item_name'     =>  __( 'New Article Category Name', 'fff' ),
    'menu_name'         =>  __( 'Categories', 'fff' )
    );  

    register_taxonomy( 'foo_categories', array( 'foo_articles' ), array(
        'hierarchical'      =>  true,
        "labels"            =>  $labels,
        "singular_label"    =>  __( 'Foo Category', 'foo'),
        'show_ui'           =>  true,
        'query_var'         =>  true,
        'rewrite'           =>  array( 'slug' => 'foo_category', 'with_front' => true )
    ));
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

**Note:** i change my post type slug by plugin settings and its `option_name` is `foo_plugin_slug` (its a client idea)

So please tell me how can i do this. Is there any hook or filter or htaccess code

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/1685

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this plugin?

**WP Permastructure**

Adds the ability to configure permalinks for custom post types using rewrite tags like %post_id% and %author%.

[image]

Download this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-permastructure/screenshots/

Comment: I think you not read my question completly

Comment: and its not working also >:(

Comment: I thought it will work for you.