# Troll the hackers by redirecting them

Tags: php, htaccess, security, wp-redirect, hacked

My website is getting somewhat popular, and with the it's increasing popularity there's an increase in the hackers.

Last night I visited my security logs and found that everyday approximately 10 people try to access

```
 /?author=1
 /?author=2
 /?author=3
 /?author=4
```

but I don't have any of these user IDs, so a 404 is generated to them.
they also run a guessing bots on usernames:

```
 admin
 administrator
 wordpress
```

Now, I want to troll them... 
so each time they try to access any of these two:

```
 1. visiting /?author=1..etc
 2. trying to login with admin username
```

I want their IP blocked off my site, and redirected to a youtube video.

I know the first one can be done with .htaccess trick, but can't quietly get this trick.
the second one I guess is done by php, but I have no experience with Wordpress although I'm pretty good with PHP.

Comment: 1) Blocking the hack attempts, I understand. 2) Passing the problem to someone else? Very unfriendly and possibly qualifies as hacking on your part.

Comment: See [Can I Prevent Enumeration of Usernames?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46469/73)

Comment: There are plenty of existing solutions around that deal with limiting login attempts. Please note that plugin recommendations are considered [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here and provide some info on what you had already reserched, tried and which more specific challenges you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this isn't exactly what you're looking for but these hackers are most likely bots and redirecting them won't matter at all. I suppose you could modify the below code if you reallllly wanted to but this will redirect anybody looking for an author back to your homepage.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?author=([0-9]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to restrict access to author's archives with `.htaccess` rule does pretty decent job. However, not everyone can edit or have access to `.htaccess`, especially on shared hosting accounts. The code below require PHP version 5.3+.

Here is the solution which deals with the problem on WordPress level. Put this code in your theme's `function.php` file:

```
<?php    
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    add_filter(
        'query_vars',
        function ( $public_query_vars ) {    
            foreach ( array( 'author_name', 'author' ) as $value ) {
                $key = array_search( $value , $public_query_vars );
                if ( false !== $key ) {
                    unset( $public_query_vars[$key] );
                }
            }    
            return $public_query_vars;
        }
    );
}
?>
```