# Username has been exposed

Tags: users, user-meta, user-access, username

I am running a WordPress installation, I am using the theme created by my own. I haven't displayed any author related information in the theme. But I am getting server logs with domain/author/author-name/.

Is there any way to get author name even if theme didn't display it?

Comment: See [Can I Prevent Enumeration of Usernames?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46469/73)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the links will always be accessible unless you disable them on your htaccess or a PHP file. If you don't have any author page, probably the users (or bots) that are reaching this page are seeing your index page.

I highly recommend you install Google Analytics code on your website to track what your users are seeing instead of a server log.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno for your response, it it can be accessible but I wonder how that user got my username, I haven't displayed author's details in theme. Is there any possibilities of getting username through xmlrpx or any other method?

Comment: Are you using a custom theme (made by yourself)? If yes, probably your RSS file is providing the author name.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bruno that is the only option left, I guess.