# How to create rewrite endpoints it in author.php?

Tags: url-rewriting, author

i'm trying to separate categories/subcategories in author.php so they each have their own endpoint link.

It's very similar to this question BUT for the life of me I can't enable the plugin provided: [How to set up sub-categories for author pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/how-to-set-up-sub-categories-for-author-pages)

The solution provided was this: https://gist.github.com/705545

I've downloaded the file, it's instructions say "enable this plugin" ... but when i put it in wp-content/plugins folder it doesn't show up on the list. I've tried putting it in a folder, and just putting the .php file in plugins folder. But it doesn't show up on the list.

**How can I enable this?** or if you have any other ideas on how to achieve these results i'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Pwn:**

Add the text *"Plugin Name:** in front of the text *"Author Endpoints Example."* You may need to remove the leading asterisk ("*").

Comment: Perfect! This did the trick. Thank you. Do you know how to check for the endpoint in author.php? If it want some content to show only on endpoint A?

Comment: @Pwn - I don't really understand how their *"endpoints"* work. Can you ask again but instead use an example URL and description of what you want it to map to? *(FYI, I'm writing a rewrite replacement system because I think the WP rewrite system if 10x more confusing than it needs to be.)*

Comment: I've actually remove the plug-in, it was producing some strange loading behavior that affected my entire site... and the code is difficult to understand. Back to square one! I will post a new question with what i'm trying to achieve. Keep me up to date with this new WP rewrite system. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That file doesn't have a plugin info header so WP doesn't recognize it as a plugin.

You need something like this:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
*/
```

see http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Thanks, I went with suggestion below instead to keep original authors comments/credit. But yes, this was the cause!